# Trying to make a tree out of four cards

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, trees, poker

Consider $\binom{13}{2} \binom43 \binom41$ where $13$ is the number of ranks and $4$ is the number of suits in a standard $52$ card deck.

One possible $2$-set out of thirteen ranks is $\{2, 3\}.$ Then for the first card we choose three suits and for each one of those we choose one suit. But which one of $\{2, 3\}$ is the first card and which one is the second card?

Comment: What is the exercise ?

Comment: What is a tree?